# Adobe Reader doesn't show .flv files. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: flash, pdf, adobe

I created a .flv file and have inserted in a beamer presentation. My problem is that as I understand to view pdf files with video I use adobe reader. No problem to install, but when I try to watch the video inserted the following message appears:

[image: message]

Which plugin should I install and how?

Comment: This https://pdfpc.github.io/ sounds like a good alternative. Also there are some dates instructions here: http://abarry.org/the-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/

Answer (score 0):

> Which plugin should I install and how?

Adobe Reader is not available in Ubuntu 14.04, the Linux [native package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/acroread-bin/) must have been removed from the partner repositories in 13.10 since it's only available up to 13.04. From what I've heard and read there were several major security issues with this last version and Adobes solution was to just drop support for Linux, because they are busy enough to patch Flash and Adobe Reader on Windows.

If you provide enough context to your question you can probably answer your question yourself:

- How did you install Adobe Reader on Linux/Ubuntu? (PlayOnLinux I assume?)

Since it's good practice to offer the slides after a presentation was held, do you think it's a good idea to make your audience suffer through the same path of hurdles and incompatibilities?

## Reasons to avoid PDF & Flash

PDF & Flash is one of the most terrible combinations from the past. PDF itself is an [overused](http://www.chrisdpeters.com/pdf-is-overused-on-the-web-lets-blame-content-management-systems/) format, embedding Java, Javascript or Flash makes it equally dangerous as using macros in other document formats and many users closely associate PDFs with printable documents.

I'm surprised to see that people still consider using such functionality which has been discouraged for many years and disabled in many existing implementations by default, yet it is one of the major ways users recently again got infected with crypto trojans.

**Show some sense of responsibility! Realize, your whole attitude of Linux and Free Desktop users are safe because we are better than the big bad companies just went down the toilet.**

Furthermore this is not how we use computers or computing devices to view documents today. Most browsers have a PDF renderer built in, all of them want to abandon Flash and have road maps for that. Flash isn't available on mobile platforms and embedded Flash players aren't very user friendly by todays standards.

## Alternatives

Browsers are more suited for presentations with multimedia content on all major platforms these days. A completely Javascript free solution doesn't appear to be available or popular right now, but browser based presentations are state of the art today. One solution I found was [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/).